# pandas/python : Get each distinct values of each column as columns and their counts as rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, one-hot-encoding

I have a data frame like this with below code,

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df.col1=['q1', 'q2', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4', 'q4']
df.col2=['b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'b']
df.col3=['p', 'q', 'r', 'p', 'q', 'q']   

df

    col1    col2    col3
0    q1        b    p
1    q2        a    q
2    q2        a    r
3    q3        c    p
4    q4        b    q
5    q4        b    q
```

Now I want to col1 wise count of each col2 and col3 variables as rows and unique values of col2 and col3 as columns, so that the final dataframe would look like,

```
col1    a    b    c    p    q    r
 q1     0    1    0    1    0    0
 q2     2    0    0    0    1    1
 q3     0    0    1    1    0    0
 q4     0    2    0    0    2    0
```

I could do this using a for loop iterating through the dataframe and storing the results, but this is computationally expensive and not a right way to do it.

Looking for alternatives pythonic/pandas way to do it efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

melt the data by `col1`, then `crosstab`:

```
m = df.melt('col1')
pd.crosstab(m['col1'], m['value']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
value col1  a  b  c  p  q  r
0       q1  0  1  0  1  0  0
1       q2  2  0  0  0  1  1
2       q3  0  0  1  1  0  0
3       q4  0  2  0  0  2  0
```